# Print and return from method on Option.isEmpty in one line using Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala I can do something like this:

```
def methodToJumpOutOf(x: Option[String]): Unit = {
   if(x.isEmpty){
      println("x is empty")
      return
   }
   // do other stuff with x
}
```

I have been wondering if I can write this w/o using if(..) by using e.g. 'fold', but I cannot get it to work:

```
def methodToJumpOutOf(x: Option[String]): Unit = {
   var valueOfX = x.fold({println("x is empty"); return}){ _ } // doesn't compile
   // do other stuff with valueOfX
}
```

Interestingly it works if I leave out the println and just write fold(return){...}.

Comment: why can't you just do def f = x.isEmpty || !x.isEmpty

Comment: If you don't need to do anything for the empty case, you could also use `x.map( y => ... )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run different code for the two possible values of `Option` then your best choice is to use `match`:

```
def methodToJumpOutOf(x: Option[String]): Unit = x match {
    case None =>
      println("x is empty")
    case Some(valueOfX) =>
      // do other stuff with valueOfX
  }
```

This makes the intent of your code clear and gives flexibility about what code you run in the two branches.

Comment: +1 - doing this saves you from needing to do a `.get` on `x` (unsafe) or explicitly calling `return` (to be avoided). Although I'd use a variable name other than `x` in the match, or rename the parameter to `maybeX`, in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Astrid You are right, I have updated my answer - thanks!

Comment: My god, I was so focused on finding a method that matches what I had in mind that I totally forgot that a simple match-case can do what I want just as good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not calculate any return value, and only produces side effect (the return type is `Unit`).

I this case, the better way in my point of view, is the following (I prefer the `if` for side effect functions):

```
def methodToJumpOutOf(x: Option[String]): Unit = {
    if(x.isEmpty) { println("x is empty") }
    else { ??? // the type of the last expression should be Unit }
}
```

However, if you want to use `fold`, you could write something like:

```
def methodToJumpOutOf(x: Option[String]): Unit = {
    x.fold(println("r"))(_ => ())
}
```

You could replace the anonymous function `i => Unit` by any other side effect function.

Notice, that is Scala, you don't have to use the `return` key work => each function return the last expression.

Comment: `Unit` is the data type . `()` is the value of type Unit. second argument to `fold` must be `i => ()`. As `i` is not used. It will be `_ => ()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cant put `return` inside other function.

What you can do is create `implicit class` to extend `Option`

```
object OptionEx {

  implicit class Ex[A](option: Option[A]) {
    def onEmpty(callback: => ()): Option[A] = {
      option.orElse({
        callback()
        Option.empty
      }
      )
    }
  }

}
```

and use it in following way:

```
import OptionEx._

def foo(x: Option[String]): Unit = {
  x
  .onEmpty{
     print("A")
     print("B")
  }
  .foreach(value => {
    // here your other code
  })
}
```